# Using mongodump to dump all databases but exclude a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

The mongodump tool seems not to support the option `--excludeCollection=someCollection` when not specifying the `--db someDb` option. We would like to dump just all databases without explicitly specifying them but exclude certain collections.

`Failed: bad option: --db is required when --excludeCollection is specified`

Is there another way to exclude certain collections?

Maybe adding a query file with `--queryFile` is an option, according to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-queryfile) it's not necessary to specify the `--collection` as with `--query`. But I couldn't find out how you write a query to do that.

We are using MongoDB 3.6.12.